# Module not found, did you mean "*js"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm building a React app with webpack and typescript. I'm using the dependency `react-financial-charts`, and it's specified correctly in `package.json` and there's the following two folders inside `node_modules`: `@react_financial_charts` and `react_financial_charts`.

However, when I use the library in my code and compile, I get the following error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-financial-charts/utils/lib/index.js 2:0-27
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './withSize' in 'C:\Users\Username\project\node_modules\@react-financial-charts\utils\lib'
Did you mean 'withSize.js'?
```

I checked the folder described in this error message, and it contains the file `withSize.js`. What gives?

My `webpack.config.js` contains this:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
```

My `index.tsx` contains:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Chart from "./StockChart"

ReactDOM.render(<Chart />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Where `StockChart.tsx` resides in the same directory and is copy-pasted from:
https://github.com/reactivemarkets/react-financial-charts/blob/master/packages/stories/src/features/StockChart.tsx

I set up the React+Webpack+Typescript project following these instructions (note that I later added the `react-financial-charts` dependency after following these instructions):

https://www.newline.co/@bespoyasov/how-to-create-a-react-typescript-application-from-scratch--676bd120

Comment: can you share the file with import?

Comment: @NikitaMazur Just done, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Fixed!

This problem was very similar to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11467.

So I merely had to add this to `webpack.config.js` (under `module` and `rules`):

```
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

particular addition..

If you used `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` to create your app, then complete solution is to **rewire** your `create-react-app` project and **add custom settings for your webpack** without eject :

1. Install `react-app-rewired`

For `create-react-app 2.x` with Webpack 4:

> ```
> npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev
> ```

For `create-react-app 1.x` or `react-scripts-ts` with Webpack 3:

> ```
> npm install react-app-rewired@1.6.2 --save-dev
> ```

2. Create a `config-overrides.js` file in the root directory

like this:

```
+-- your-project
|   +-- config-overrides.js
|   +-- node_modules
|   +-- package.json
|   +-- public
|   +-- README.md
|   +-- src
```

fill it with this code:

> ```
> module.exports = function override(config, env) {
>     // New config, e.g. config.plugins.push...
>
>     config.module.rules = [...config.module.rules, 
>         {
>             test: /\.m?js/,
>             resolve: {
>               fullySpecified: false
>             }
>         }
>       ]
>
>     return config
> }
> ```

3. 'Flip' the existing calls to react-scripts in npm scripts for start, build and test

from:

> /* package.json */
>
> ```
>   "scripts": {
>    "start": "react-scripts start",
>    "build": "react-scripts build",
>    "test": "react-scripts test",
>    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
> }
> ```

To:

> /* package.json */
>
> ```
>   "scripts": {
>    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
>    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
>    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
>    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
> }
> ```

**Note: Do NOT flip the call for the eject script.** That gets run only once for a project, after which you are given full control over the webpack configuration making react-app-rewired no longer required. There are no configuration options to rewire for the eject script.

4. Start the Dev Server

> ```
> npm start
> ```

5. Build your app

> ```
> npm run build
> ```